# Can I have your feedback on this sentence? Is it wordy?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, style, adverbial-phrases

> This is like raising one's head, **as far as its maximum angling capacity allows**, and ‘looking up to’ the sky.

I wonder if the bold section is too wordy.  Is there an adverb that captures this meaning?

Comment: I think most writers would put this much less formally: "...turning your head as far as it will stretch and..."

Comment: But is my phrasing correct? Does it read soothingly? Is it expressive regardless of its formality?

Comment: 'Soothingly', no! *Maximum angling capacity* reads like something from a physiology textbook - hardly the sort of thing you want in what appears to be a motivational text.

Comment: Yes, it's clumsy style for my taste. Unwieldy. Overwrought. Unclear. *Tilting back one's head as far as it will go / as far as possible / (more formal): maximally / to its maximum extent. Alternatively, extending one's neck back... Bending one's head back... (What gets bent/extended is the neck, technically, but I would accept *head* there (again, personally) without pause because the meaning is so clear.

Comment: Sounds like an instruction for an android [& I don't mean a phone] ;)  If it's an instruction, to a human being, how about 'as far as you can' ? [an aside, no-one except Prince Charles ever actually says 'one' these days]

Comment: @Tetsujin, oh yes one does! I think that actually sounds a lot more natural than the alternatives in this context. Agree re the actual 'as far as you can' though. 'As far as it will go' would work too.

Comment: "Tilt your head back as far as you can..."

Comment: "This is like tilting one's head back as far as possible and looking up to the sky" is a possibility.  "Angling capacity" sounds more like a fishing term to me.  :)

Answer (score 1):

So, to make an answer out of the comments:

> This is like raising one's head, **tilting it as far as it will go**, and ‘looking up to’ the sky.

As mentioned in the comments, the maximum angling capacity sounds like a measurement in the specifications of a robot. Angling is not generally used with stretching or tilting any parts of the body as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You could also crane your neck, which means to stretch or bend or twist your neck or head to look at something.

Comment: That usually means to stretch to look over the top of something, though, doesn't it?  Seems that way to me.

Comment: Typically but in general it kinda technically means to just put your neck back the farthest it will go, or in any other position that would be uncomfortable if sustained.